# Close keyboard on button press in react-native

Tags: react-native

When i press an input in react-native , the keyboard pops an opens.
I would like to close the keyboard (ONLY) when pressing some button.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can dismiss the keyboard by using `Keyboard.dismiss`.

```
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';
<Touchable onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>...</Touchable>
```

If you're using a `ScrollView` you'll need to set `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` prop to `true`.

Comment: Working perfectly!

Comment: @oblador did you mean this one: react-native-dismiss-keyboard when you wrote from 'dismissKeyboard'?

Comment: Thank you.Working for me

Comment: What if we are using a FlatList inside ?